# How to know if a Python multiprocessing.Lock is released or not?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

```
>>> l = Lock()
>>> l.acquire()
True
>>> l.release()
>>> l.release()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: semaphore or lock released too many times
```

throws a ValueError exception. How can I prevent to release a lock more than once? Something like l.is_released() ?

Comment: Normally, you'd just write your code so that it doesn't try to release a lock more times than it is acquired...

Comment: This could include using a flag is_the_lock_locked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear. You either need to use semaphores instead of locks or check if lock is locked.

Python's locks are not the same as locks on .Net, for example. Python's Lock once unlocks releases ALL other threads that acquired() on the same lock and blocked for the time being. Any thread can release and all go at the same time. So, instead of doing second relase, do

```
if l.locked():
    l.release()
```

If you want "queue" behavior, where only one tread will get ownership of a lock once some other releases, use Semaphore, Event or some other similar class that allows nested locking and queuing behavior.

It's interesting to note that other languages/loolkits, like .Net, do lock queuing natively, where threads can pile up lock.acquire in order, block and take ownership of the lock object in the order of acquire queue, not release all at once.

(Edit: forgot to put parents as in "if l.locked: l.realse()". Corrected the code. Lock.locked is confirmed to be a present method in cPython 2.6.x, 3.x, IronPython 2.6.1)

Comment: >>> from multiprocessing import Lock
>>> Lock().locked
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Lock' object has no attribute 'locked'

Comment: You can do a non-blocking acquire as in "not lock.acquire(False)" checking the return code.

Comment: @kristopolous instead of doing a non-blocking acquire and checking the return code, just put the release call in a try except block, catching ValueError exceptions.

Comment: @ddotsenko do you mean that if more than one process is waiting for a lock, they will all acquire that lock simultaneously once it's released? Perhaps I just misunderstand your answer but this would defeat the purpose of a lock, and is not my experience in python, at least with 2.7.x. Any chance you could clarify or give a supporting link? Thanks.

Comment: Lock from `multiprocessing` module has no method`locked`, but `threading` module has method `locked`

Answer (score 7):

The expectation is that the context that acquired the lock should be aware of when it should release it.  In what circumstance would you attempt to release it multiple times?

Comment: Say the thread has acquired the lock but while doing the work there is an exception, i have try except block, so i want to check when exception occur the lock was acquired or not to avoid deadlock.

Comment: Either make your try more granular or take advantage of context managers (with my_lock:) to guarantee release of your lock.

Answer (score 2):

Create a quick wrapper function to check:

```
from multiprocessing import Lock

l = Lock()

def is_locked():
    locked = l.acquire(block=False)
    if locked == False:
        return True
    else:
        l.release()
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Since lock.acquire() returns true if it successfully acquires the lock, you can store the state of locking in a local variable and then encapsulate lock.acquire() and the subsequent code inside a try-finally block. Then in the finally block, you can query the variable to see if the lock has been acquired or not. If it has, release.