# Test if a lock has been acquired in python

Tags: python, locking

I have Python 2.7.3. I am trying to use Lock object to allow only one instance of my script to run at a time.
I am using:

```
from mutiprocessing import Lock
lock = Lock()
if lock.locked() == False:
    lock.acquire()
    lock.release()
```

as I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619738/how-to-know-if-a-python-multiprocessing-lock-is-released-or-not)
But I am getting this error:

```
if lock.locked():
AttributeError: 'Lock' object has no attribute 'locked'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `locked` method - for good reasons.

```
if lock.locked():
    lock.acquire()
    lock.release()
```

If you do code like this, the state of the lock can change between the testing of the if condition and the acquire.

[`acquire` allows non-blocking operation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire):

```
if lock.acquire(False):
    #...
    lock.release()
```

This will only execute the code inside the `if` if there's nothing else holding the lock - otherwise, it'll skip execution entirely.

Comment: Actually he wants *the opposite*. The pseudo code of the OP would acquire the lock *only* if it was currently locked by someone else. `acquire(False)` does the opposite. Also it'd be good to provide an example using context managers: `with lock: # ...` is the same as `try: lock.acquire() #...; finally: lock.release()` which is less error prone.

Comment: @Bakuriu Indeed, that's what the pseudo-code does, although it doesn't match the question description - I'm unsure whats the exact expected behaviour here, so I think we'll have to wait for clarification. I'm not aware of a way to test a lock (i.e.:not block) using context managers?

Comment: Interestingly, a `locked` method was introduced in Python 3.7.